How to instrument http.ServeMux with OpenTelemetry?
I'm looking for a quick way to instrument http.ServeMux for OpenTelemetry. My mux handles multiple routes.
For Elastic APM, I can do it quickly like:
rootMux = apmhttp.Wrap(rootMux)

But with OpenTelemetry, it seems that I need to individually instrument each route, like:
helloHandler = otelhttp.NewHandler(helloHandler, "hello")
rootMux.Handle("hello", helloHandler)

Is there an easier way?

Try wrapping http.ServeMux, it's a http.Handler:
    otelServeMux := otelhttp.NewHandler(http.DefaultServeMux, "ServeMux")
    err = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", otelServeMux)


This will make all top level OTEL spans to be named “ServeMux”. I want the span names to match my API routes.

You can create an Open Telemetry middleware and pass that to each route:
middleware := otelmux.Middleware("my-server")
rootMux.Handle("hello", middleware(helloHandler))
rootMux.Handle("goodbye", middleware(goodbyeHandler))

Alternatively, if you're willing to use a third party router like Gorilla Mux it's much more straightforward:
rootMux := mux.NewRouter()
rootMux.Use(otelmux.Middleware("my-server"))
rootMux.Handle("hello", helloHandler)

